# Manual install of Vim

Tags: vim, installation

I have downloaded the source for VIM (7.3) and compiled it successfully with a make command on a Linux platform. I do not want to run make install though as I think this will overwrite the current version of VIM already installed which will cause problems for other users on the server using VIM 7.0. I would just like to run the newly compiled VIM binary for my user account by putting it in my home bin folder but cannot find it in the VIM folder

Is it possible to do this and if yes, where is the binary after running make?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide the `prefix` option for the `configure` script to set the installation directory:

Example:

```
mkdir /home/john/vim/ && ./configure --prefix /home/john/vim/ && make && make install
```

Then it will install the vim to `/home/john/vim/` and won't write anything over.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for a great tip which will work for any compile from source application.